# How to make JTabbedPane abide by insertion order?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I want to have certain tabs in my JTabbedPane be in a certain place but the JTabbedPane reorders them and scrambles them on different rows.

I have been looking at Stackoverflow for about 3 hours now with no working solution to my problem. The only thing I have seen mentioned was making my own TabbedPaneLayout class.

Here you can see I'm adding my panels to the tabbed pane. The problem is that it does not add the panels from the first added to the last added. It scrambles them to make them fit based on their text I believe.

```
JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    pane.addTab("Pane " + i, new Panel());
}
```

Originally discovering the JTabbedPane, I thought the tabs would be by insertion order. You can recreate this by using the above code. I want the tabs to go from 0-12 in order or the first added to be on the top and the last added to be on the very last row at the bottom.

This is what it looks like currently:
`http://prntscr.com/o55zog`

Comment: They're not "scrambled" at all. It has tabs 0 to 4 in the front row and 5 to 11 in the back row, in insertion order. What is it you want? The rows swapped around?

Comment: @khelwood It is a little hard to explain so imagine the loop above and each tab's position is based on its insertion order. What I notice is that when tabs reach the next line they switch with the top taps and the first tabs to be added are now on the bottom when I want them to be on the top (like insertion order).

Comment: Is [add(Component component,
            int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20int)) what you are looking for ?

Comment: *The only thing I have seen mentioned was making my own TabbedPaneLayout class* - that would be a good guess (and I would guess very complicated). What you desecribe if the default layout of the tabs. It may not be what you want but it is well defined by the layout. Playing with the insertion order can (potentially) give you the effect you want, but it will not work if, for example, the width of the tabbed pane is changed and you now need 3 rows to display the tabs.